# SMTP client module

Tags: elixir

I'm new to elixir and would really like some feedback on my code. MY background has been node -> laravel -> ruby / rails -> go -> elixir. I'm building an SMTP client and would like to make sure I'm using common patterns before I continue.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
defmodule Client do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for `Smtpclient`.
  """

  use Agent

  def start_link(_opts) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end


  def connect(pid, tld) do
      set_value(pid, "tld", tld)
      {:ok, records} = DNS.resolve(tld, :mx)
      Enum.sort_by(records, fn(r) -> elem(r, 0) end)
      sock = do_connect(records, 0)
      set_socket(pid, sock)
      set_value(pid, "hostname", tld)
      {:ok, sock}
  end

  @spec helo(any) :: any
  def helo(pid) do
      already_helloed = get_value(pid, "already_helloed")
      if already_helloed do # if already helloed return early
        {:error, "already helloed"}
      end
      sock = get_socket(pid)
      tld = get_value(pid, "tld")
      sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("HELO #{tld}")
      set_value(pid, "already_helloed", true)
      sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!
  end

  def noop(pid) do
    try do
      sock = get_socket(pid)
      sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("NOOP")
      sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!
    rescue
      Socker.Error -> {:error, :no_connection}
    end
  end

  def quit(sock) do
      try do
        sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("QUIT")
        sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!
        sock |> Socket.close!()
      rescue
        Socket.Error -> {:error, "something is wrong"}
      end
  end

  def rctp_to(pid, email) do
    try do
      sock = get_socket(pid)
      sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("RCPT_TO #{email}")
      sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!
    rescue
      Socker.Error -> {:error, "something is wrong"}
    end
  end

  defp set_socket(pid, sock) do
    Agent.update(pid, &Map.put(&1, "socket", sock))
  end

  defp get_socket(pid) do
    Agent.get(pid, &Map.get(&1, "socket"))
  end

  defp set_value(pid, key, value) do
    Agent.update(pid, &Map.put(&1, key, value))
  end

  defp get_value(pid, key) do
    Agent.get(pid, &Map.get(&1, key))
  end

  defp do_connect(hostnames, i) do
    try do
      host = elem(Enum.at(hostnames, i), 1)
      Socket.TCP.connect!(to_string(host), 25, packet: :line)
    rescue
        Socket.Error ->
          if Enum.at(hostnames, i) == nil do
            {:error, "all mx servers down"}
          end
          do_connect(hostnames, i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd question what's the purpose of a process (Agent) here. There could be multiple reasons for a process:

1. Sharing the same instance of SMTP client with multiple processes, controlling rates and so on.
2. Isolation of failure. It goes both ways - not only prevents buggy SMTP client from crashing the rest of the application, but also prevents other buggy parts of the application from hindering sending correctly prepared messages.
3. Visibility of failure (through logging) if the process is started under a supervisor.

Note that I don't mention restarts here because it's a bit more controversial.

> Imagine you experience some network problem which results in the SMTP client process being terminated right when it's spawned. The supervisor will restart such process immediately and as it dies again will do it again and again, in the end the restart limits will be reached and this time the supervisor will terminate itself. If it was attached to another supervisor it will be restarted immediately and the cycle repeats again and again in the end killing whole the OTP application. Thus automatic restarts may be undesirable and some might want such processes to be started using `temporary` restart strategy.

With all of the above, I suggest to ensure the operations you submit to the agent are self-sufficient and atomic, so that if some other process attempts to use your SMTP client process concurrently, it doesn't go into incorrect state.

For example `connect/2` is not atomic as all the execution happens in the client and the agent process is used only as a mutable storage. If 2 clients attempted to call it simultaneously the resulting state might be built from bits sent by both clients. Compare that with:

```elixir
defmodule SMTP.Client do
  # internal state could be stored in a struct
  defstruct [:sock]

  def start_link(pid, tld) do
    Agent.start_link(fn ->
      {:ok, records} = DNS.resolve(tld, :mx)

      # all values are immutable so the returned sorted list
      # should be assigned to a binding (variable name) which
      # happens to look the same way as an existing binding
      records = Enum.sort_by(records, fn(r) -> elem(r, 0) end)

      # if `{:error, _}` is returned in some cases, then success
      # should result in `{:ok, result}`
      {:ok, sock} = do_connect(records, 0)

      # as the protocol requires this to be the first operation
      # it should be executed right after the connection
      # so the clients shouldn't decide whether this is needed or not
      :ok = sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("HELO #{tld}")

      # the response should be tested on correctness and success
      {:ok, _response} = sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!

      %__MODULE__{sock: sock}
    end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def send(pid, email, body) do
    Agent.get_and_update(pid, fn state ->
      %__MODULE__{sock: sock} = state
      :ok = sock |> Socket.Stream.send!("RCPT_TO #{email}")
      {:ok, _response} = sock |> Socket.Stream.recv!
      # send the body
      ...
      {:ok, state}
    rescue
      # this is controversial as now we don't know the protocol state
      # so we cannot reliably use this socket and should either
      # allow whole process to crash (but that'll result in all currently
      # scheduled calls to it to fail) or to close this socket and create
      # a new one using the same approach as in `spawn_link`.
      error -> {{:error, error}, state}
    end)
  end

  # all other functions are private and are not available to the users
  # of this module.
  ...
end
```

Here the API clients are given is very high level and it allows us to follow the protocol internally without leaking protocol details to the clients. The concurrent clients won't interfere others work as every operation is atomic from their point of view.